# Connecting to MongoDB from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mongodb

I'm trying to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) with MATLAB. Although there is no [supported driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) for MATLAB, there is one for Java. Fortunately I was able to use it to connect to db, etc.
I [downloaded](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads) the latest (2.1) version of jar-file and install it with JAVAADDPATH. Then I tried to follow the [Java tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial).

Here is the code

```
javaaddpath('c:\MATLAB\myJavaClasses\mongo-2.1.jar')

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;

m = Mongo(); % connect to local db
db = m.getDB('test'); % get db object
colls = db.getCollectionNames(); % get collection names
coll = db.getCollection('things'); % get DBCollection object

doc = BasicDBObject();
doc.put('name', 'MongoDB');
doc.put('type', 'database');
doc.put('count', 1);
info = BasicDBObject();
info.put('x', 203);
info.put('y', 102);
doc.put('info', info);
coll.insert(doc);
```

Here is where I stacked. `coll` supposed to be `DBCollection` object, but actually is object of `com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection` class. So the last command returns the error:

**??? No method 'insert' with matching signature found for class 'com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection'.**

In the tutorial the `coll` variable is created explicitly as DBCollection object:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection")
```

Am I doing something wrong in MATLAB? Any ideas?

Another minor question about `colls` variable. It's `com.mongodb.util.OrderedSet` class and contains list of names of all collections in the db. How could I convert it to MATLAB's cell array?

---

**Update**: In addition to [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886461/connecting-to-mongodb-from-matlab/3886712#3886712) this works as well:

```
wc = com.mongodb.WriteConcern();
coll.insert(doc,wc)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick check:

```
methodsview(coll)        %# or: methods(coll, '-full')
```

shows that it expects an array:

```
com.mongodb.WriteResult  insert(com.mongodb.DBObject[])
```

Try this instead:

```
doc(1) = BasicDBObject();
doc(1).put('name', 'MongoDB');
doc(1).put('type', 'database');
...
coll.insert(doc);
```

---

Note: If you are using Java in MATLAB, I suggest you use the [CheckClass](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26947-checkclass) and [UIInspect](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methodspropertiescallbacks-of-an-object) utilities by [Yair Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman)

Comment: +1. The method does expect an array (or rather a vararg). Since Java5, there are now varargs, so from Java you can just call it with the DBObject directly. Does this mean varargs are not supported in the MATLAB Java bindings?

Comment: As I recall, Java varargs are simply syntactic sugar for the array construct

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks a lot. I'm not so experienced with Java in MATLAB but learning.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, saved me some real RTMFing.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a driver built expressly to connect MongoDB and Matlab.  It is built on top of the mongo-c-driver.  Source can be found on github:

https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/mongo-matlab-driver

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to compile on Mac OS, and seems to have been abandoned (or at least certainly isn't actively being developed/supported)...

Comment: Beware of this.  I spend several hours trying to link in all the external files by constantly googling all the errors I was getting and  it still didnt work.  The author provides about two vague lines about how ur supposed to implement this.

Comment: i can only confirm this. I had also difficulties getting it to run on windows. The java driver or even the **C# driver (see [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) )** are better options.

Answer (score 2):

For the minor question about converting the list of collections use the `toArray()` method.

```
>> cList=cell(colls.toArray())

cList = 
  'foo'
  'system.indexes'
  'things'
```